# south running schemamigration on all installed apps at the same time

Tags: django, database-migration, django-south

I want to add schemamigration for my django project. I am hosting it on openshift. I want to create schemamigration files on all models and migrate them at once on deployment, (for the first time). There is migrate command that executes the migration scripts for all apps but there isn't a command to create migration scripts for all apps at once. I want this to run on openshift and add it on my deploy hook. Is there an automated way or must I write my own way?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: http://codeblow.com/questions/django-south-creating-schemamigration-in-excess-of-one-application/

Basically:

```
APPS_TO_WATCH = ['myapp','myotherapp','toomanyapps']  
def migration():  
    for app in APPS_TO_WATCH:  
        local('python manage.py schemamigration %s --auto' % app)
```